# Writing test for angular directive with dynamic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('templates',function() {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: function(s,e) {
        switch (e.template) {
            case 'temp1':                   
                return 'temp1.html';
            case 'temp2':
                return 'temp1.htm2';
            default:
                // do nothing... ;
        }
    }
};
});
```

I can get it to compile in my test but i'm not sure how to test if the correct templates are being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to test here. But as a feel good test you can just load a template into cache and do a test if specific element has been rendered or not as a feel good test.

Example:-

```
   describe('templates', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $templateCache, $compile) {
        // Set an arbitrary template to test
        $templateCache.put('temp1.html', '<div class="test">Hello</div>');
        element = angular.element("<templates  template='temp1'></templates>");
        $compile(element)(scope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }));


    it('Should load template', function () {
       expect(element.find('.test').length).toEqual(1); //Test if element has loaded template properly
       expect(element.find('.test').text()).toEqual("Hello");
    });
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/n50dLG?p=preview)**

On a different note your directive can break if there is no `template` provided, it is required to return a template from templateurl function. Also you can make this simple directive more generic as well.

```
.directive('templates',function() {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: function(e,attr) {
      return attr.template + ".html"
   };
});
```

How ever, there is nothing to be tested here because you will just end up testing angular's templateUrl function evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. I was just mainly stumped on getting the templates into the testing